# I know the difference between assert and verify but wanted to know the syntax of verify in selenium webdriver with java

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I know the difference between assert and verify but wanted to know the syntax of verify in selenium web driver with java

Answer (score 0):

There is no definite syntax for verify similar to Assert. Verify is what we used to mention the if or if else conditional statement in out program.